# Cordova Twilio plugin connection status

Tags: java, javascript, cordova, twilio

I am using the following Cordova plugin for Twilio https://github.com/jefflinwood/twilio_client_phonegap

I am not able to get the connection status on status change.

Please if anyone knows how to listen for status change or request the status at any time help me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing the same problem and changed a bit the native plugin implementation to fix this.
You can find the fork at: https://github.com/ebariaux/twilio_client_phonegap

Plugin has not been tested extensively, just made that change that got me the functionality I wanted.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply I see you have modified the IOS code I need the plugin for Android